# How to add the custom headers to https requesting curl PHP script?

Tags: php, curl, https

In curl PHP script, we add the headers by the curl_setopt `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option. It works fine with HTTP request like search.yahoo.com but I tried it with the HTTPS request it doesn't work.

I have disable SSL peer verification by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to false. Is there way to implement it?

Comment: Try [`curl_error()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-error.php) after `curl_exec()` and show us the error message if there is any.

Comment: yes i have tried it gives coudn't connect to the host error

Comment: You have to provide the full code you use. Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: And you can reach the host if you ping it or do a traceroute for that url? But as @hindmost said: provide us your curl code section.

Comment: i cant post the code bcoz i am posting this from mobile and so there is problem while posting code but i will but i will say u what  i want to do

Comment: i want to implement the real host proxy by sending the host headers i have done all the necessary options of curl returntransfer max redirs ssl verifyer also for tracking http request that is header out i test this code with search.yahoo.com it works fine also tries with wap.in it works again but i used it with fb it returns couldn't connect to host

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add the custom headers to the https request curl php script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881273/how-to-add-the-custom-headers-to-the-https-request-curl-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick solution
add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  before curl_exec()

here $ch curl_init() object;

Do [refer here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) for alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to download the CA certificate with your browser and save it as X.509. This will make you able to accept all certificates issued by the CA. Then use the following CURL options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "path_to_CA_certificate.crt");
```

CURLOPT_VERIFYHOST has different options, you can try 0 first in order to aviod CN check, and if it works then try with 2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to sent the host header to them it can be sent by any other way