# How to add the custom headers to the https request curl PHP script?

Tags: php, curl

I am writing the following code

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init(); 
$h=array("Host:v.airtellive.com");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://facebook.com");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$h);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follow header redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4); // Limit redirections to 4
$p=curl_getinfo($ch);
$o=curl_exec($ch);
if($o==null)
var_dump (curl_error($ch)); 
$headers=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
print_r($headers);
echo "<xmp>";
echo $o;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

but it gives me error:

> could not resolve the host

If I use this script with `search.yahoo.com` it works fine. Actually, I want to create the realhost proxy by sending the host headers.

Comment: You cannot set `Host` header. It will set by CURL automatically

Comment: is there another method for set host headers

Comment: You **cannot** change `Host` header. It will be set automatically according to given URL's host

Comment: then how it works with search.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Headers for CURL mus be set like this

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array(
                "AUTH_USERNAME: {$username}",
                "AUTH_PASSWORD: {$password}",
            ));
$curlReturn = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Any number of custom headers can be sent as array in this.

Comment: where you are completed [ square bracket

Comment: sorry and thanks that was used in php latest version where `arrays` can be used as `[]`