# cURL PHP ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection

Tags: php, ajax, ssl, curl

I'm trying to send an `Ajax` request using `cURL PHP` but it gives the error

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection
```

while I'm able to `login` to same server.

I've tried this

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1 );
```

and `Ajax` request is something like that

```
$header = array('Accept' => '*/*', 
"X-Requested-With" => "XMLHttpRequest", 
"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

$data = array('ClientNumber=999999&OrderClass=ContractOrders&ShowAll=ContractOrders&ShowPerPage=500');

echo $page = Spider::spider($header, 'https://wfs.nursefinders.com/MasterConsole/displayorders.cfm?ShowAll=ContractOrders', 'https://wfs.nursefinders.com/MasterConsole/BuildOrderDisplaySection.cfm', FALSE, $data[0]);
```

**Note** in `spider` function, first argument is `header`, second is `referrer` third is `url to access`, fourth doesn't matter `it's for cookie file` and fifth is `data o post`

I'm using `UBUNTU 14.10` and `cURL Version` is `curl 7.37.1` according to this command `/usr/bin/curl -V`

and same as printing by `php phpinfo()`

Please help

Comment: try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774221/how-to-add-the-custom-headers-to-https-requesting-curl-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for your problem is that the server you are communicating with does not support your SSL protocol.

There is a page here with information on that: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

For more direct information, try looking into the API Documentation for the required connection protocol for their server. They may have provided a sample that will connect.

Answer (score 0):

This server is terrible broken. It does not support the most compatible SSLv23 handshake and will just hang if one tries it. It only supports explicit SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0 handshakes. From looking at the source code of cURL it seems to me, that all variations of enforcing TLS1.0+ will do a SSLv23 handshake, which the server can not do:

```
-- curl-7.41.0/lib/vtls/openssl.c
1719   default:
1720   case CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT:
1721   case CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1:
1722   case CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0:
1723   case CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1:
1724   case CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2:
1725     /* it will be handled later with the context options */
1726     req_method = SSLv23_client_method();
```

This leaves only the option of using the insecure SSL 3.0, that is

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3 );
```

While I have no PHP to test with, a short test with `curl -1` vs. `curl -3` on the command line confirms that CURLOPT_SSLVERSION of  `1` will not work while `3` should work.